# Can I create channel without using the make function?

Tags: go, channel

The following code works okay

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan string)
    go subRountine(c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}

func subRountine(c chan string) {
    c <- "hello"
}
```

Is there any other method to create a channel without the make function?
Something like this but this sample does not work

```
func main() {
    var c chan string
    go subRountine(c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}

func subRountine(c chan string) {
    c <- "hello"
}
```

Comment: *"Is there any other method to create a channel without the make function?"* -- No. Channel types do not support composite literals and `var c chan t` only declares the variable, it does not initialize the channel, leaving it `nil`.

Comment: What do you have against `make()`? What's wrong with using it?

Comment: Nothing wrong. I am learning a new language and want to know all the options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL;DR

No way around it: you must use `make`.

### More details

```
var c chan string
```

merely declares a channel variable, but without initialising the channel! This is problematic because, [as the language spec puts it](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Channel_types),

> The value of an uninitialized channel is `nil`.

and

> A `nil` channel is never ready for communication.

In other words, sending and/or receiving to a `nil` channel is blocking. Although [`nil` channel values *can* be useful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynoY2xz-F8s&t=24m54s), you must initialise a channel at some stage if you ever want to perform *channel communications* (send or receive) on it.

As mkopriva writes in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626679/create-a-channel-without-make-function-go#comment126589585_71626679), Go provides only one way of initialising a channel:

> A new, initialized channel value can be made using the built-in function `make`, which takes the channel type and an optional *capacity* as arguments:
>
> ```
> make(chan int, 100)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

No! Declaring a channel with `var` is different from creating it. Then you should create by `make`:

```golang
  var c chan string
  c = make(chan string)
```

With the difference that now you can make c in underlying scops and use it outside of them.

*Note that you shouldn't put colons before the equals sign in this way.*

Comment: @FrankieHung I mean when the method described was used. I updated the answer.